# Sharing logins across different devices

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, browser, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a project where we have multiple computers (running chrome) that are used to present webpages automatically.
Some of the webpages displayed on these computers require a login.
Currently we need to remotely login into every computer and enter passwords in order for them to load the pages. However, I would like to be able to login to a site only once and then share the logins throught the different computers.

Is there some way to synchronize sessions across chrome clients, so that I only log on to the machine once?

Or is it required to use something like Selenium to type in passwords. I don't really like selenium for this because:
1. It usually stops working when someone upgrades the browser
2. It seems like alot of work: Need to "reverse engineer" the login page for each site...

Are there any other approaches I can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your Questions straight :

`Is there some way to synchronize sessions across chrome clients` : **No**, each chrome client will open a seperate session hence you have to login seperately. Inorder to synchronize these sessions you have to use `Chrome Profiles` and save them on each system.

`Or is it required to use something like Selenium to type in passwords` : This would be the most **optimum way**.

`It usually stops working when someone upgrades the browser` : You can uncheck/disable `Automatic Updates` to remain at a particular **`Chrome Browser Version`**

`It seems like alot of work: Need to "reverse engineer" the login page for each site` : **`Login Page`** for each site will render differently as a **`DOM Tree`**. Hence there is no short cuts.